# Conjugacy classes and orders of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices, finite-groups, finite-fields

The following are prime decompositions in $\Bbb{Z}_7[x]$:

$x^8+1= (x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)(x^2+3x-1)(x^2+4x-1)$

$x^4+1= (x^2+3x+1)(x^2+4x+1)$

(a) Give representatives for the conjugacy classes of elements of order dividing 16 in $Gl_2(\Bbb{Z}_7)$ and give the order of each.

(b) Show that there are no elements of order 32 in $Gl_2(\Bbb{Z}_7)$.

(a) We can write the rational canonical forms as representatives.

$x^2-x-1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$x^2+x-1  \rightarrow  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

$x^2+3x-1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  1 \\1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$

$x^2+4x-1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  1 \\1 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$

$x^3+3x+1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  -1 \\1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$

$x^2+4x+1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  -1 \\1 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$

$x^2+1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  -1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

The first four matrices have order 16, since they satisfy $x^8+1=0$ so $x^8=-1 \implies (x^8)^2 = 1$. The last two have order 8, since $x^4=-1 \implies x^8=1$.

(b)We don’t know the factorization of $x^{16}+1$, so we can’t check whether or not the matrices that satisfy it actually belong to $Gl_2(\Bbb{Z}_7)$. I wasn’t able to tell whether this was even reducible in $Z_7[x]$ to begin with, so I was kind of stuck here, and I was wondering if anybody could give me a hint...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess your "representatives" are companion matrices. However, you did it the wrong way. The companion matrix of $x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -a_0 \\ 1 & -a_1\end{pmatrix}$, so for example, $x^2 + 1$ has the **invertible** companion matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @azimut Thanks, I think I mixed it up. I will edit my answer. Is part (a) correct besides that?

Comment: The idea to use the rational normal forms is good. However, your solution is lacking the arguments, which might be the reason for your list being incomplete. Compare to the solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part (a)** Let $A\in\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_7)$ be a matrix whose order divides $16$.
Then $A^{16} - I = 0$, so the minimal polynomial $f$ of $A$ is a divisor of $x^{16} - 1$.
We have
$$x^{16} - 1
= (x^8 + 1)(x^8 - 1)
= (x^8 + 1)(x^4 + 1)(x^2 + 1)(x+1)(x - 1)
$$

Since $A$ is $2\times 2$, the degree of $f$ is at most $2$.
Using the fact that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_7$ (since $-1$ is not a square mod $7$) and the given factorizations of $x^4 + 1$ and $x^8+ 1$, we can enumerate all the possibilities for $f$.
Furthermore, in all the cases we can immediately give the exact order of $A$, which is given by the smallest exponent $k$ such that $f$ divides $x^k - 1$. Representatives for $A$ are given by the possible rational normal forms (which happen to be uniquely determined by $f$ in all cases). We get the following list:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
f & \operatorname{ord}(A) & \text{representatives} \\
\hline
x-1 & 1 & I \\
x+1 & 2 & -I \\
(x-1)(x+1) & 2 & \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 + 1 & 4 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 + 3x + 1 & 8 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & -3\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 + 4x + 1 & 8 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 - x - 1 & 16 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 + x - 1 & 16 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 + 3x - 1 & 16 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & -3\end{pmatrix} \\
x^2 + 4x - 1 & 16 & \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{array}
$$

**Part (b)**
Assume that that there is a matrix $A\in\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_7)$ of order $32$.
Then the minimal polynomial $f$ of $A$ divides $x^{32} - 1$, but not $x^{16} - 1$ and is of degree $1$ or $2$.
In the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ there is a zero $a$ of $f$ of multiplicative order $32$. (Otherwise, all zeros would have an order dividing $16$. Since $x^{32} - 1$ doesn't have multiple zeros, $f$ does not have multiple roots and so $f$ would divide $x^{16} - 1$.)

From $f(a) = 0$ we get $[\mathbb{Z}_7(a) : \mathbb{Z}_7] \leq \deg(f) = 2$.
So $\mathbb{Z}_7(a)$ is a field of size $7^1$ or $7^2$. Because up to isomorphisms, finite fields are uniquely determined by their order, and because $\mathbb{F}_7$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{49}$, we get $a\in\mathbb{F}_{49}^\times$.
Since $\mathbb{F}_{49}^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_{48}$ does not contain an element of order $32$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: @Thanks, but I'm not sure where $\Bbb{F}^{\times}_{49}$ came from??

Comment: @Artus: I've added some more details. Better?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's better now.